# Google Pie Chart + PHP + mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

*Thanks for mbelton. My code works good now, and I also modified the following code I post.*

I'm trying to use Google Pie chart to perform the year of sales. First I have HTML file which to let user choose the year they wish to review; Second, based on the $year be selected, I code PHP to connect to mysql to grab related sales data; Third I create a pieData table to store the String Quarter and double sales number; and then JavaScript to get pie char. I run the code doesn't show any errors but I don't see pie chart showing up. Can please someone tell me where to modify to make it work? Thanks.

```
 $year = $_POST['year'];  
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect("root", "account", "passwd", "testDB")
      or die(mysqli_error());
 $query = "SELECT Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 from sales where year LIKE '$year'";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

 /*get the values of each quarter, and store in new table:pieData.
 * if user choose year of 2012, then the new table should look like:
 * Quarter     Number
 * ------------------
 * Q1         127.24
 * Q2         106.54
 * Q3          88.04
 * Q4         120.89
*/
 while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               $Q1 = $info['Q1'];
               $Q2 = $info['Q2'];
               $Q3 = $info['Q3'];
               $Q4 = $info['Q4'];

            }

 $pieData = array(
                  array('Quarter', 'Number'),
                  array('Q1', (double)$Q1),
                  array('Q2', (double)$Q2),
                  array('Q3', (double)$Q3),
                  array('Q4', (double)$Q4)
    );

 $jsonTable = json_encode($pieData);

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //load package
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            // Create and populate the data table.
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                <?php echo $jsonTable; ?>

            );


            var options = {
                title:"Sales Pie"
            };

            // Create and draw the visualization.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("piechart"));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to send the request and then using a callback to generate the chart or is this done purely on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think error in your code is in opening/closing `<script` tag and in `.arrayToDataTable` you need to remove square brackets [ ]

Change code to:

```
<?php

 $Q1 = 127.24;
 $Q2 = 106.54;
 $Q3 = 88.04;
 $Q4 = 120.89;

 $pieData = array(
              array('Quarter', 'Number'),
              array('Q1', (double)$Q1),
              array('Q2', (double)$Q2),
              array('Q3', (double)$Q3),
              array('Q4', (double)$Q4)
);

 $jsonTable = json_encode($pieData);
?>  

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        <?php  echo $jsonTable; ?>
    );

    var options = {
      title: "My Daily Activities"
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("piechart"));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
 <body>
   <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I removed the [] tags from arrayToDataTable, and I modified the single quote to double quote, then Pie Chart shows up! It's very beautiful, thanks for the help.